# How to create buffers around points in ArcMap when there is a lack of OID

Tags: arcmap, point, buffer

I want to create buffers around points in ArcMap. Using the Buffer (Analyst) tool, I indicated 100m buffers around my points of interest.

I get the error:

ERROR 000339: Input price, ads (v8) - school.csv Events does not have OIDs
Failed to execute (Buffer).
Failed at Wed Nov 07 16:49:00 2018 (Elapsed Time: 0.01 seconds)

The points are in a CSV file. How do I correct this error in order to generate the buffers?

Comment: To confirm - you have the XY events layer already? If so, right click on your Events layer, and export to a shapefile or feature class in a Geodatabase. This output can now be used for buffers.

Comment: Thank you for our answer. I have the XY events layer. When trying to export, a message appears that says: 'There was an error exporting the layer'.

Comment: Any further details in the error message? Are you trying to put it in a Geodatabase with an accidental extension such as .shp?

Comment: I have tried saving it in several locations. The same short message appears (no further details in the message I'm afraid). What I do know is that the csv file does not have an OID field, could this be an issue?

Comment: No, the CSV doesn't need one, it just needs a) X values (e.g. longitude), b) Y values (e.g. latitude) and c) other attribute(s) such as the name of a store. To confirm, did you create it by adding data then right clicking, add XY events, or something similar?

Comment: Where are you saving it (to shapefile or feature class)? What is the name you are using (naming conventions may cause error)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. I added the points into the table of contents by 'the Add Data' option, selected the CSV file. I have tried, add XY events-- where I get the message of not having the OID field. And I have also tried exporting data directly-- In this case I save it as schools.dbf  -- and the mesage now says ' there was an error exporint the table'.

Comment: Try copy the table to a table in a file geodatabase, then use this as input to  xy event layer, copy features and buffer

Comment: Thank you Bera, can you please provide more detail as to how copy the table to a table in a file geodatabase? Thank you!

Comment: The message about not having an OID therefore can't display on a map is normal.  Try to save as .shp instead of .DBF, or if you want it in GDB, do not include any extension and make sure the save as type is "File and personal GDB feature classes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding the CSV via Add Data tool and using right click | `Display XY Data` or the tool `Make XY Event Layer`, it is normal to receive a "Table Does not have Object-ID field" message. Just make sure you remember to include the coordinate system the data was created in such as WGS84.

[image: Example warning message in Display XY Data]

After the event layer is created, Right click in the Table of Contents and Export the data.

[image: Export Data screenprint]

[image: Export Data screenprint]

Because the window here is pretty small, I find it easier to control the file name and location by clicking the little yellow folder icon on the right side.

Two of your export options are

1. **Feature Class in a Geodatabase**. In this case, navigate to the geodatabase you want to store the data and provide a feature class name. Do not include a file extension.

[image: Save dialog box for feature class in GDB]

2. **Shapefile.** In this case, navigate to the folder you want to store the data and provide a shapefile name. Change the type to Shapefile. The file extension automatically changes to .shp.

[image: Save dialog box for shapefile]

Once the data is exported, use the exported data as the input for your buffer process.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed computers and followed your instructions and it is now working.

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear that. If this was helpful for your issue, there's an option to set it as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark. (If you're still having trouble on the original computer, you can create a new question with additional details about any errors on the other machine and reference this question.)